# Lightning Web Component - Create Contact

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am went through alot of the Trailheads for Salesforce. The documentation is interesting at best. With that said I tried an example from a Blog to understand the actual code and IDE of Visual Studio Code.

https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2018/12/introduction-to-lightning-web.html

I followed the above blog, but the component doesnt show on the component. Yes, my domain is registered because I see my Hello World Component.

Here is the code.

I wanted a good example on how to create a page that would create a record. Also is there a way to check in Salesforce to see if the HTML exists? The IDE says that it is successful but it would be nice to see it in Salesforce like the Classic Salesforce edition.

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Contact" icon-name="standard:contact">

    <lightning-record-form object-api-name={objectApiName} record-id={recordId} 
                           fields={fields}></lightning-record-form>

</lightning-card>
</template>


import { LightningElement , api, track} from 'lwc';

export default class LWBDemoComponent extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
@api objectApiName;
@track fields = ['Name', 'Title', 'Phone', 'Email'];
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" 
fqn="LWCDemoComponent">
<apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple case of not setting up your meta.xml file content correctly. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) for details.

You need isExposed to be true and you'll want to set up some targets/targetConfigs as needed.

Comment: Ugh... I wonder why they didnt have isexposed as True....

Comment: A component only used within another component does not need to be exposed. You set isExposed true to allow the Lightning App Builder to show it for adding to a page for some form.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your .XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```